# Why Isn't Kafka Consumer Updating code as Expected?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to update the campaign status dynamically when the current time is the same as the campaign's start or end time using the node-schedule package, and it's working fine. The only problem is that when I restart my server, it loses all of the scheduler information and does not update the campaign status, so I save the campaign information in kafka topics and consume messages from that topic when the server restarts, but it is not working. I don't understand the problem.

The producer code:

```
export class CampaignProducer {
    private readonly producer: Producer;
    private readonly campaignTopic = CAMPAIGN_TOPIC.campaignTopic;

    constructor(private readonly kafka: Kafka) {
        this.producer = this.kafka.producer();
    }

    async sendCampaignMessage(campaignId: string, startDate: Date): Promise<void> {
        await this.producer.connect();
        await this.producer.send({
            topic: this.campaignTopic,
            messages: [{ value: JSON.stringify({ campaignId, startDate }) }],
        });
    }
}
```

The consumer code:

```
export class CampaignConsumer implements OnModuleInit {
    private consumer: Consumer;
    private readonly campaignTopic = CAMPAIGN_TOPIC.campaignTopic;
    private readonly groupId = CAMPAIGN_TOPIC.campaignGroup;

    constructor(private readonly kafka: Kafka, private readonly campaignService: ClientCampaignService) {
        this.consumer = this.kafka.consumer({ groupId: this.groupId });
    }

    async onModuleInit() {
        await this.consumeSchedulerInfo();
    }

    async consumeSchedulerInfo() {
        try {
            await this.consumer.connect();
            await this.consumer.subscribe({ topic: this.campaignTopic, fromBeginning: true });

            await this.consumer.run({
                autoCommit: true,
                eachMessage: async ({ message }: EachMessagePayload) => {
                    try {
                        const { campaignId, startDate } = JSON.parse(message.value.toString());
                        await this.campaignService.scheduleCampaignStart(campaignId, startDate);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error processing scheduler message:', error);
                    }
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Kafka consumer error:', error);
        }
    }
}
```

The data from the kafka: `{"campaignId":"64ff1042a4c66b4c3bc70b05","startDate":"2023-09-11T13:05:00.000Z","endDate":"2023-09-11T13:07:00.000Z"}`

The campaign from the database(MongoDB):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64ff1042a4c66b4c3bc70b05"),
    "campaignName" : "new campaign",
    "storeId" : ObjectId("64f02cb62d554f12069d3a36"),
    "startDateWithTime" : ISODate("2023-09-11T13:05:00.000+0000"),
    "endDateWithTime" : ISODate("2023-09-11T13:07:00.000+0000"),
    "campaignStatus" : "Not Started",
}
```

The campaign creation code which is used to send the message to the kafka:

```
async addCampaign(data: Partial<ICampaign>, files) {
        const directory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', UPLOAD_DIRECTORY.CAMPAIGN);
        await createDirectoryIfNotExists(directory);

        const filePaths = await uploadFiles(files, directory);

        const campaignDataWithFiles = { ...data, files: filePaths };
        const campaign = await this.campaignModel.create(campaignDataWithFiles);

        await this.scheduleCampaignAction(
            campaign._id.toString(),
            campaign.startDateWithTime,
            this.updateStatusToInProgress.bind(this)
        );
        await this.scheduleCampaignAction(campaign._id.toString(), campaign.endDateWithTime, this.updateStatusToClosed.bind(this));

        return campaign;
    }
```

The kafka service file code:

```
export class KafkaService implements OnModuleInit {
    private kafka: Kafka;
    private readonly kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig;
    private campaignProducer: CampaignProducer;
    private campaignConsumer: CampaignConsumer;

    constructor(private readonly campaignService: ClientCampaignService) {
        this.kafkaConfig = {
            clientId: 'your-client-id',
            brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
        };
        this.kafka = new Kafka(this.kafkaConfig);
        this.campaignProducer = new CampaignProducer(this.kafka);
        this.campaignConsumer = new CampaignConsumer(this.kafka, this.campaignService);
    }

    async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
        await this.campaignConsumer.consumeSchedulerInfo();
    }

    getCampaignConsumer(): CampaignConsumer {
        return this.campaignConsumer;
    }

    getCampaignProducer(): CampaignProducer {
        return this.campaignProducer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding else statements to your conditional and adding more logging to see what the issue might be

Comment: So what do you mean "it is not working"? What is expected and what is actual?